# Experiencing challenge creating Schema Extension on Azure AD

Tags: php, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am using the following function to create Schema Extensions on Azure AD but I end up getting the error below:

```
{
  "code":"InternalServerError",
   "message":"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
}
```

Here is my function below:

```
public function createExtension($id, $description, $targetTypes) {
    $token = $this - > getToken();
    // $graph = new Graph();
    // $graph->setAccessToken($token);

    $headers = [
        'Authorization: Bearer '.$token,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    ];

    $data = json_encode([
        'id' => $id, 
        'description' => $description, 
        'targetTypes' => ["User"], 
        'status' => 'Available'
    ]);

    $ch = curl_init('https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/schemaExtensions');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $arr = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
    $logger = $this - > container - > get('monolog.logger.azure');
    $logger - > info('Values', ['ch' => $arr]);
    return $arr - > id;
}
```

Comment: You cannot set the `status` when creating an extension. It will always start off with a status of `InDevelopment`. You also failed to provide any `properties`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main* issue with your code is that you're missing the required `properties` field.

As is described in the [Microsoft Graph doc on creating schema extensions](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/schemaextension_post_schemaextensions), you must supply `id`, `description`, `targetTypes` and `properties` when creating a new `schemaExtension`. (The `owner` attribute is optional.)

The following code should work. (Note that I've also switched to using the v1.0 endpoint, since this is already out of beta.)

```
$token = $this->getToken(); // Assume this does what the name implies

$headers = [
    'Authorization: Bearer ' . $token,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
];

$data = json_encode([
    'id' => 'size', 
    'description' => 'Height and shoe size', 
    'targetTypes' => ['User'],
    'properties' => [
        [
            'id' => 'shoeSize',
            'type' => 'Integer',
        ],
        [
            'id' => 'height',
            'type' => 'Integer',
        ],
        [
            'id' => 'tShirtSize',
            'type' => 'String',
        ],
    ]
]);

$ch = curl_init('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/schemaExtensions');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$schemaExtension = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
return $schemaExtension->id;
```

If you wanted to use the [Microsoft Graph SDK for PHP](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php), the code would look very similar:

```
use Microsoft\Graph\Graph;
use Microsoft\Graph\Model;

$token = $this->getToken(); // Assume this does what the name implies

$graph = new Graph();
$graph->setAccessToken($token);

$newSchemaExtension = new Model\SchemaExtension([
    'id' => 'sizes', 
    'description' => 'Height, shoe and shirt size', 
    'targetTypes' => ['User'],
    'properties' => [
        [
            'name' => 'shoeSize',
            'type' => 'Integer',
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'height',
            'type' => 'Integer',
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'shirtSize',
            'type' => 'String',
        ],
    ]
]);

$schemaExtension = $graph->createRequest('POST', '/schemaExtensions')
                        ->attachBody($newSchemaExtension)
                        ->setReturnType(Model\SchemaExtension::class)
                        ->execute();
return $schemaExtension->getId();
```

*The missing `properties` property was the main issue, but you also have a couple other issues:

- You're trying to reference the `id` attribute with `$arr->id`, but `json_decode($string, true)` returns an associative array, so you would use `$arr['id']` instead.
- You're trying to set the `status` of the schema extension during creation, which also causes an error (though it's a different one). When first creating the schema extension, omit the `status` field and update it later when you're ready.